# Mechanics of the Python schedule library

Tags: python, schedule

I'd like to use the [Schedule](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) library for Python, but I don't quite understand how it works.

```
def job():
    % my program here

schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
```

If I run this code once from the terminal, will it always run `job` at 10:30 every day? Or do I also need to add something like:

```
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

(I'm getting all this code from the [github](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) for the library)

Or do I need to [continuously run the scheduler without blocking the main thread](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread) as described in the FAQ for the library?

Does my terminal always need to be open?

Comment: Well you probably have to do like the FAQ says. Why not use some OS task scheduler to just call `job` everyday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the github doc you had linked, as well as the [developer interface](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#module-schedule), you do have to put `run_pending()` and some length of `sleep` in an infinite loop.

You do not need to run the scheduler from another thread, unless you program does something in the main thread other than scheduling. If you are only using it to schedule, there is no need.

If you close the terminal, the whole program closes, so yes the terminal needs to stay open.

Comment: Well, you could disown the scripy, e.g. `python schedule_script.py & disown` but it would crash if the script try to read or write from stdin/stdout.